# What is the time complexity of computing $\frac{1}{2^n} {{n}\choose{(n+2)/2}}$

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, discrete-mathematics

What is the time complexity of computing $\frac{1}{2^n} {{n}\choose{(n+2)/2}}$?

$$\frac{1}{2^n} {{n}\choose{(n+2)/2}} = \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{n(n-1)\cdots ((n-2)/2)}{((n+2)/2) (n/2) \cdots 1}$$

The numerator and denominator in $\frac{n(n-1)\cdots ((n-2)/2)}{((n+2)/2) (n/2) \cdots 1}$ will take $O(n)$ multiplications.

$2^n$ will take $n$ multiplications.

So in total, there will be $O(n)$ multiplications. Is it the correct time complexity?

Comment: The number of multiplications is indeed $O(n)$ if that's what you mean by time complexity.  Note that you can compute $2^n$ in $\log(n)$ multiplications by binary exponentiation. But what about the cost of the multiplications themselves?

Comment: I don't know.      $ $

Comment: Maybe there is a way to compute the binomial that takes less multiplications? (And yes, you have to state what you want to count resp. what constitutes constant effort).

Comment: @Raphael: What can constitutes constant effort, usually in analysis of algorithms?

Comment: Depends. Considering multiplications and divisions constant effort, but not exponentiation, is quite common, but not helpful in all contexts. I guess you want to count all arithmetic operations.

Comment: You can compute binomial coefficients via Pascal's triangle, though I doubt if it's any faster.